# Access own type from within static method (Typescript)

Tags: typescript

I'd like to maintain an array of members in my models, and have generic ways of accessing those static arrays.

Suppose I have:

```
class A {
    static _records: A[]

    static getRecords(): A[] {
        ...
    }
}

class B extends A {}

// Some other file
let allBs: B = B.getRecords();
```

What I'd like to do is declare A with something like:

```
class A {
    static _records: OWN_CLASS[]

    static getRecords(): OWN_CLASS[] {
        ...
    }
}
```

So that subclasses point to their own type, rather than their parent type's. Is there a way to do this without explicit casting or am I looking at an anti-pattern?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In more recent versions of typescript:

```
class MyType {
    public static INSTANCES: MyType[];

    public static get<T extends MyType>(): T[] {
        return <T[]>this.INSTANCES.filter((instance) => instance instanceof this);
    }
}

class MyType2 extends MyType {
}

const myType2s: MyType2[] = MyType2.get();
```

Comment: Take this that this is loosely typed. The inferred return type is only bounded on one end. This means that `const myType2s: MyType2[] = MyType.get();` will pass the compiler but will likely lead to runtime exceptions as the actual type of the returned instances will be `MyType` instead of `MyType2`.

Comment: No, the function is running inside of MyType2, so "this" refers to MyType2 and not MyType. I've tested this in a more complete solution and it works well, although the above should be `return <T[]>this.INSTANCES...` and not `return <T[]>MyType.INSTANCES...` so I'll fix that up.

Comment: Take the following assignment as an example: `const myType2s: MyType2[] = MyType.get();`. The statement `MyType.get()` will return a runtime value of type `MyType[]`, as you described. However, since we've declared the variable as being of type `MyType2[]`, the compiler will instead infer the generic parameter `T` to be the declared type (`MyType2`). This is allowed since the generic parameter is only bounded as *any* subtype of `MyType`. This means that our assignment will *pass type-checking* even though the returned values will be of runtime type `MyType` instead of `MyType2`.

Comment: @pixelpax, I'm not sure why you changed the accepted answer from mine to this, but bear in mind that you do lose type safety by using this solution as mentioned in my previous comments. It will compile successfully but will lead to runtime errors if you are not careful to ensure that your declared types match the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported. I would not consider this an anti-pattern, though each individual use-case itself may or may not be appropriate. Be careful to ensure that the types returned by the static function always match the type of the referrer for the static function.

```
class MyType {
    public static INSTANCES: this[];

    public static get(): this[] {
        return MyType.INSTANCES.filter((instance) => instance instanceof this);
    }
}

class MyType2 extends MyType {
}

const myType2s: MyType2[] = MyType2.get();
```

---

Edit:

It sounds like this solution might not work on some versions of TypeScript.

There is an open TypeScript ticket for this ([#5863](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-366007069)). It sounds like it should be working but may require a slightly different solution depending on the version of TypeScript that you are using.

The linked comment from **bjouhier** provides the following option:

```
class Singleton {
    private static _instance?: Singleton;

    public static getInstance<T extends Singleton>(this: { new(): T }) {
        const constr = this as any as typeof Singleton; // hack
        return (constr._instance || (constr._instance = new this())) as T;
    }
}

class Foo extends Singleton {
    public foo() { console.log('foo!'); }
}

class Bar extends Singleton {
    public bar() { console.log('bar!');}
}

Foo.getInstance().foo();
Bar.getInstance().bar();
```

As bjouhier mentions, this solution requires a bit of non-ideal casting, but it appears to work.

Comment: It looks perfect! but I tried it in the TypeScript playground. It says that `this type is only available for non-static members of class or interface` would I need to enable some polyfill to get this to work?

Comment: That's strange. I'm running TypeScript 2.4.2 and not running into issues with it (although 2.4.2 is admittedly a little bit old). You might try looking at TypeScript issue [#5863](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-366007069) for more information. The linked comment provides a potential solution that I've added to this answer.